# How can I see two different pdf documents on screen split vertically?

Tags: windows, pdf

How can I see two different pdf documents on screen split vertically and independently scrollable?

Comment: Which PDF Software do you use?

Comment: Just open your document in different instances of pdf viewer and snap them to different sides of desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned what software you are using here are some generic bits of advice:

#### Browser based PDF viewers:

1. simply open the PDF documents you want in separate tabs
2. click (and hold) on the tab to drag it out to a new window
3. drag the new window to the left or right edges of the screen and it will "snap" into half the display, or use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right arrow</kbd>

#### External PDF Reader

Adobe Reader opens PDF documents in separate Windows already. You can simply drag the new window to the left or right edges of the screen and it will "snap" into half the display, or use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right arrow</kbd>.